# checking amicable number in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm, dosbox

i wrote a code for checking if two numbers are amicables. the code works for few pairs (220 & 284-amicable, 1184 & 1210- amicable, 34566 &  3455- not amicable)
but for some pair it dosen't work- 66928 & 66992. is should be amicable but it prints not amicable. what is the problem?

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA

NUM1 DD ?
NUM2 DD ?
NUMBER DD ?
N DW 1
TEN DD 10
DIVNUM DD 2
DIVSUM DD 0
EnterNumber DB 'ENTER NUMBER: ',13,10,'$'
NOSTR DB 13,10,'NOT AMICABLE NUMBERS',13,10,'$'
YESSTR DB 13,10,'AMICABLE NUMBERS',13,10,'$'

.CODE
.386
getNum PROC NEAR
     MOV AH,9            ; Set print option for int 21h
     MOV DX,OFFSET EnterNumber  ;  Set  DS:DX to point to EnterNumber
     INT 21h             ;  Print DisplayString
     ;FIRST A DIGIT
     MOV AH,1
     INT 21h
     SUB AL,'0'
     MOV AH, 0
     MOV NUMBER,EAX
     MOV N,1
GET_DIGIT:          ;This loop gets all the rest of the digits until 'enter' has been insert and make the digits a nunmber.
     CMP N,9
     JE sof
     MOV AH,1
     INT 21H
     CMP AL,13
     ;AL=='ENTER KEY'
     JE sof
     MOV BX,AX
     SUB BL,'0'
     MOV BH,0
     MOV EAX,number
     MUL TEN
     ADD EAX,EBX
     MOV number,EAX
     INC N
     JMP GET_DIGIT
SOF:
     RET
     getNum ENDP

PNum PROC NEAR
CHECK:
     MOV ECX,DIVNUM
     CMP ECX,NUMBER
     JE FINISH
     MOV EAX,NUMBER
     MOV EDX,0
     DIV DIVNUM
     CMP EDX,0
     JE SUM
     INC DIVNUM 
     JMP CHECK
SUM:
     MOV EBX,DIVNUM
     ADD DIVSUM, EBX    
     INC DIVNUM  
     JMP CHECK
FINISH:
     INC DIVSUM
     RET
     PNum ENDP

MAIN:
     MOV AX,@DATA
     MOV DS,AX
     CALL getNum
     ; ASIGNING NUM1
     MOV EAX,NUMBER
     MOV NUM1,EAX
     MOV NUMBER,0
     CALL getNum
     ;ASIGNING NUM2
     MOV EAX,NUMBER
     MOV NUM2,EAX
         ;CHECKIN NUM1 DIVIDERS.
     MOV EAX,NUM1
     MOV NUMBER,EAX
     CALL PNum
     MOV ECX,DIVSUM
     CMP ECX,NUM2
     JE NEXT
     JMP PRINTNO
NEXT:
     MOV DIVSUM,0
     MOV DIVNUM,2
     MOV EAX,NUM2
     MOV NUMBER,EAX
     CALL PNum
     MOV ECX,DIVSUM
     CMP ECX,NUM1
     JE PRINTYES
     JMP PRINTNO

PRINTNO:
     MOV AH,9            ; Set print option for int 21h
     MOV DX,OFFSET NOSTR  ;  Set  DS:DX to point to NOSTR
     INT 21h             ;  Print DisplayString
     JMP END_CODE
PRINTYES:
     MOV AH,9            ; Set print option for int 21h
     MOV DX,OFFSET YESSTR  ;  Set  DS:DX to point to YESSTR
     INT 21h             ;  Print DisplayString
END_CODE:
     MOV AH,4Ch              ; Set terminate option for int 21h
     INT 21h                 ; Return to DOS (terminate program)
                             ;
     END MAIN  ; Set "main:" as first executable statement
```

[image: prints examples]

[image: the pair that doesn't work]

Comment: How about debugger? You will get stuck all the time without it. If you don't have DOS one, maybe consider switching development platform to win/linux 32/64b (with some up to date assembler). In this case it would take only short time to try out the problematic input in step by step manner.

Comment: i do debugging all the time but for numbers this size it will take hours.. that's why i asked you guys for help. maybe you can see a problem that i have missed.

Comment: Don't even joke like this. If I'm correct about the problem, you would have wrong values in `NUM1`/`NUM2` ahead of `CHECK` call, a simple view of memory would tell you something went wrong. About debugging `CHECK`: simply put breakpoint at `RET`, and do only 3-4 iterations step by step to verify all code paths (division, summing, skipping), then run the rest till the `RET` and verify result. Anyway, if you think you can post the incorrect code on SO every time to get others to debug it, then I need just popcorn and wait for inevitable. So improving your debugging skills is only way forward.

Comment: i meant that maybe people who are more skilled than me, like you, can see something i did wrong in the code that i'm not aware of. i didn't mean i want someone to do debugging for me. i already did debug with smaller numbers and everything went well from getting the number to summing the divisors. but for some reason for this pair only the code doesn't work as it should

Comment: The warning light should have been for you that both numbers are >= `65536`. And you know, what is `65536`, right? It's sort of quite magic number in 16 bit world. Again, simple breakpoint after both `call getNum` and storing `NUM1/NUM2` + check of memory would instantly tell you the number reading is wrong. It would probably require more effort to figure out *why*, but to localize problem you would need like 5min. Try it now as exercise, after I told you how.

Comment: btw, the whole problem was i didn't reset my 'EAX' to 0 in the 'getNum' function.

Comment: thx i didn't know about the breakpoint thing. it helped alot

Comment: Np, you're welcome. BTW it's not the only problem. You also don't handle empty number correctly (first input from user is "enter" without digit), you don't clear `ebx` in the same way as `eax` in `getNum`, you will get into trouble in `CHECK` routine when user enters "1" and overflow of `DIVSUM` is not handled (nor in my version). That's all I **see** (I didn't run it) (and 99% is fixed in my version, so you should probably take a look a try to find how I resolved them, both on instruction and logical level).

Answer (score 1):

I can't run tasm/dos things, so I will just guess, in `getNum`:

```
     ...
     SUB AL,'0'
     MOV AH, 0
  ; ^^ you clear bits b8-b15
     MOV NUMBER,EAX
  ; ^^ but you store b0-b31 (bits b16-b31 undefined)
```

There are few more places in your source which made me a bit frown (I mean the "bug frown", not the "not my style frown", which I had for the major part of source, but in the end the style looks to be reasonable for somebody learning assembly, keeping things simple, which probably saves you from many bugs).

I'm adding few modifications of your source, but I didn't verify they work, so search for my comments and try to verify on your own the change works as intended (also I'm using lowercase, as I like it that way more, plus you can easily see parts of code I modified).

Let me know if it works, and also ask if you don't understand some change.

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA

NUM1 DD ?
NUM2 DD ?
NUMBER DD ?
DIVSUM DD ?

EnterNumber DB 'ENTER NUMBER: ',13,10,'$'
NOSTR DB 13,10,'NOT AMICABLE NUMBERS',13,10,'$'
YESSTR DB 13,10,'AMICABLE NUMBERS',13,10,'$'

.CODE
.386

getNum PROC NEAR
     ; display user prompt
     MOV AH,9            ; Set print option for int 21h
     MOV DX,OFFSET EnterNumber  ;  Set  DS:DX to point to EnterNumber
     INT 21h             ;  Print DisplayString
     ; get decimal number as separate digit characters
     xor edx,edx         ; number value = 0
     xor cl,cl           ; number of digits = 0
GET_DIGIT:
     ; This loop gets all of the digits until 'enter'
     MOV AH,1
     INT 21h             ; read single char (with echo on screen)
     CMP AL,13           ; AL=='ENTER KEY'
     JE getNum_exit
     ; calculate value of digit and add it to total number
     SUB AL,'0'
     movzx eax,al        ; eax = 32b zero extend al
     ; number (edx) = number*10 + eax
     lea edx,[edx+edx*4] ; number *= 5
     lea edx,[eax+edx*2] ; number = number*2 + eax
     inc cl
     cmp cl,9
     jb GET_DIGIT        ; 9 digits at most
getNum_exit:
     mov [NUMBER],edx
     RET
     getNum ENDP

PNum PROC NEAR
     mov ecx,2           ; divisor (ecx) = 2 (first to try)
     xor ebx,ebx         ; divisor_sum (ebx) = 0
CHECK:
     MOV EAX,NUMBER
     xor edx,edx         ; edx:eax = 64b NUMBER
     cmp ecx,eax         ; finish when divisor >= number
     jae FINISH
     div ecx             ; edx = number mod divisor (eax = quotient)
     test edx,edx        ; AND x,x will set ZF=1 when x==0 (faster cmp x,0)
     jnz not_a_divisor   ; some remainder, not a divisor of number, skip sum
     add ebx,ecx         ; divisor_sum += divisor
not_a_divisor:
     inc ecx             ; next divisor
     JMP CHECK
FINISH:
     inc ebx             ; +1 for "1" divisor
     mov [DIVSUM],ebx    ; return sum in memory global
     RET
     PNum ENDP

MAIN:
     MOV AX,@DATA
     MOV DS,AX
     CALL getNum
     ; ASIGNING NUM1
     MOV EAX,NUMBER
     MOV NUM1,EAX
     CALL getNum

     ; in surrounding code I removed all temporary variables initialization
     ; these belong into the routines themselves, you should set only arguments
     ; outside (ahead of CALL).
     ; My modification to routines make them to init all internal variables
     ; correctly without depending on the external state.

     ;ASIGNING NUM2
     MOV EAX,NUMBER
     MOV NUM2,EAX
         ;CHECKIN NUM1 DIVIDERS.
     MOV EAX,NUM1
     MOV NUMBER,EAX
     CALL PNum
     MOV ECX,DIVSUM
     CMP ECX,NUM2
     JE NEXT
     JMP PRINTNO
NEXT:
     MOV EAX,NUM2
     MOV NUMBER,EAX
     CALL PNum
     MOV ECX,DIVSUM
     CMP ECX,NUM1
     JE PRINTYES
     JMP PRINTNO

PRINTNO:
     MOV AH,9            ; Set print option for int 21h
     MOV DX,OFFSET NOSTR  ;  Set  DS:DX to point to NOSTR
     INT 21h             ;  Print DisplayString
     JMP END_CODE
PRINTYES:
     MOV AH,9            ; Set print option for int 21h
     MOV DX,OFFSET YESSTR  ;  Set  DS:DX to point to YESSTR
     INT 21h             ;  Print DisplayString
END_CODE:
     MOV AH,4Ch              ; Set terminate option for int 21h
     INT 21h                 ; Return to DOS (terminate program)
                             ;
     END MAIN  ; Set "main:" as first executable statement
```